# Generate Dynamic Menu and SubMenu from database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have two tables in my database i.e. Menu and Sub_Menu... I have retrieved the data from those two tables using JOIN queries and it looks like this

```
`SELECT menu.menu_name AS menu_name, sub_menu.sub_menu_name FROM menu LEFT JOIN user_category ON menu.user_category_id = user_category.user_category_id LEFT JOIN sub_menu ON menu.menu_id = sub_menu.menu_id WHERE user_category.user_category_name = "Normal";`
```

After this what i have done is I have used `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` to store the results. Now, the problem rises here. When I print the output, the last value of the duplicate key is only displayed and others are omitted... What i want to display is a unique key with multiple values.. I have tried it using `LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` but can't get it right !!!

`

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> menuSubMenu = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();`

`ArrayList<String> subMenu = null;`

`String key = null;`

            while (rs.next()) {
                key = rs.getString("menu_name");

                if (key.equals(rs.getString("menu_name"))) {
                    key = rs.getString("menu_name");
                    subMenu = new ArrayList<String>();
                    subMenu.add(rs.getString("sub_menu_name"));
                } else {
                    subMenu = null;
                }

                menuSubMenu.put(key, subMenu);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you code sample is a bit confusing but you can try this way:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> menuSubMenu = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        while(true){
            String key = rs.getString("menu_name");
            if(!menuSubMenu.containsKey(key)){
                menuSubMenu.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            menuSubMenu.get(key).add(rs.getString("sub_menu_name"));
        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you so much... it works .. now i know .. what was wrong with my code... thanks again !!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that the problem is where you are putting the data into your map instead of where you take it out. You need to make certain that you are putting the array list back into the map after you create a new one and that you're pulling that array list back out the next time you encounter that word.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example or any tutorial ?? thanks a ton !

Comment: Post your code where you're adding the String and I'll have a look.

Comment: thank you for your concern... but my code works now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree [The Thom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967330/the-thom%20The%20Thom) You have to check for already existing entries in your Hashmap:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> menuSubMenu = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

while (rs.next()) {
    final String            key     = rs.getString("menu_name");
    final ArrayList<String> subMenu = menuSubMenu.get(key);

    if (subMenu == null) {
        subMenu = new ArrayList<String>();
        menuSubMenu.put(key, subMenu);
    }


    subMenu.add(rs.getString("sub_menu_name"));
}
```